# I can't use a module that uses classes on React (create-react-app)

Tags: reactjs

The error

```
 /node_modules/myLibrary/lib/index.js 97:8
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (97:8)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| class SomeClass {
|   
>   property;
|   property2;
|   property3;
```

I can't figure out what's wrong.
If I use object with function properties it's work fine.
If I use a class, I can't use it on node environment but not on React.

Comment: Oh, I explained myself badly.
This is a require on top of a functional component, the problem isn't JSX, it's the module itself, that contains a class and webpack doesn't like it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## I solved it using [esbuild](https://esbuild.github.io).

I created a file `build.js`

```js
require('esbuild').build({
    entryPoints: [
        "lib/myLibrary.js",
    ],
    bundle: true,
    minifyWhitespace: true,
    minifySyntax: false,
    minifyIdentifiers: false,
    format: "cjs",
    platform: "neutral",
    outdir: 'out',
}).catch(() => process.exit(1))
```

Then I run `node ./build.js` and then I published the resulting file on NPM.
That solved the errors.

**Edit: esbuild doesn't preserve JSDoc, Rollup does.**

## Alternative:  [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/)

I used this config on `rollup.config.js`:

```
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';

const config = {
    input: "src/myLibrary.js",
    output: {
        file: "myLibrary.js",
        format: "cjs",
        exports: "auto",
    },
    plugins: [commonjs()],
};

export default config;
```